# iPhone's Address Book's A-Z bar style swipe/drag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

Do you guys think is possible to build for the ipad browser a function where you can touch-and-drag-to-scroll like you can see on the Contacts Book on your iphone when you click or click'n'drag the A-Z list bar on the right?

I believe the browser should have the scroll detection in real-time like a desktop browser to do that right? any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Basically you'll want to combine these two tutorials:

- [iPhone like sliding headers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/iphone-like-sliding-headers/)
- [Slider Gallery](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slider-gallery/)

Which is something I'm looking forward to implementing myself for a demo application I'm working on